# Slicing a matrix in the givens argument of a theano function

Tags: python, slice, pca, theano

I have the following piece of code, in which I attempt to apply PCA to the MNIST dataset.

```
X_train, y_train = mnist.data[:60000] / 255., mnist.target[:60000]

X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
X_train, y_train = X_train[:5000], y_train[:5000]

pca = PCA(M=2)

X = T.matrix('X', dtype='float64')
i = T.scalar()
j = T.scalar()

# Theano function which fits the model to the
# data i.e. applies dimensionality reduction
transform = theano.function(
   inputs=[i, j],
   outputs=pca.transform(X),
   givens={
        X: X_train[(y_train == i) + (y_train == j)]
   }
)

X_transformed = transform(i, j)
y_ = y_train[(y_train == i) + (y_train == j)]
```

As can be seen in the code above, I try to substitute `X` with a slice of the training dataset in the `givens` params. The above code, however, results in the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, vector) (of Variable <TensorType(float64, vector)>) into Type TensorType(float64, matrix). You can try to manually convert <TensorType(float64, vector)> into a TensorType(float64, matrix).
```

Which implies that I am trying to assign a vector to a matrix, which isn't the behaviour I would expect (I doubled checked using numpy). I also tried a different approach, whereby I index the training dataset X_train with the array of booleans directly instead of using indices are performing the slices my self, but that also didn't work.

```
X_train, y_train = mnist.data[:60000] / 255., mnist.target[:60000]

X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
X_train, y_train = X_train[:5000], y_train[:5000]

pca = PCA(M=2)

X = T.matrix('X', dtype='float64')
bool_arr = T.vector()

# Theano function which fits the model to the
# data i.e. applies dimensionality reduction
transform = theano.function(
   inputs=[i, j],
   outputs=pca.transform(X),
   givens={
        X: X_train[bool_arr]
   }
)

X_transformed = transform((y_train == i) + (y_train == j))
y_ = y_train[(y_train == i) + (y_train == j)]
```

Which gives the following error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

The only approach that did work is using disregarding the `givens` param, and using only the inputs and outputs, as such:

```
X = T.matrix('X', dtype='float64')

# Theano function which fits the model to the
# data i.e. applies dimensionality reduction
transform = theano.function(
    inputs=[X],
    outputs=pca.transform(X),
)

X_ = X_train[(y_train == i) + (y_train == j)]
y_ = y_train[(y_train == i) + (y_train == j)]

X_transformed = transform(X_)
```

None the less, I feel curious as to why my first two approaches do not work, and would appreciate if any one could point me to where I might be going wrong, since I am just starting with Theano.

Comment: Where does the `PCA` come from?

Comment: @cfh That is just a class that I implemented using `theano`

Answer (score 1):

The [theano documentation](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/function.html#module-function) states:

> `givens` (iterable over pairs `(Var1, Var2)` of Variables. List, tuple or
>   dict. The `Var1` and `Var2` in each pair must have the same Type.) –
>   specific substitutions to make in the computation graph (`Var2` replaces
>   `Var1`).

And in the [tutorial examples](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#basictutexamples), there is the statement (emphasis mine)

> In practice, a good way of thinking about the `givens` is as a mechanism
>   that allows you to replace any part of your formula with a different
>   expression that evaluates **to a tensor of same shape and dtype**.

So, you cannot replace a matrix by a vector by means of the `givens` parameter since they don't have the same shape.